# PHP MySQL select random rows where a row is different

Tags: php, mysql, random

What Im Trying to achieve is selecting multiple rows randomly where a certain column is different from the last for example

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `column_for_duplicate_values` != '$thelastkey' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

the column for multiple values would hold for example:

```
1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2, 5 , 6, 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 11 , 11 ,  11 , 19
```

and I want to select 1 from each. So I would get

```
1 , 2 , 5 , 6 , 11 , 19
```

Comment: That is not random. That is distinct

Comment: But i want to select random rows theres around 95,000 records with these ID's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with my solution may be that it's

1. slow
2. not applicable

   You need to have a primary unique id in your `mytable`

   ```
     SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (
              SELECT id FROM (
                       SELECT id, column_for_duplicate_values 
                       FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND()) AS rand 
                       GROUP BY column_for_duplicate_values
                       ORDER BY RAND()) LIMIT 10;
   ```

The main concept is to first get a random list of all values with their id and the column you want to have unique values.

From this result we group by the value we only want to have once and only return the id. The main table will then select 10 random id's form this list.

I tried it with one of my db's. Should work with any table that has a unique id and some random other column.

If you append `ORDER BY id ASC` will also sort the id's.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect speed isnt a problem I have lots of processing power.

Comment: I updated the query and moved the limit to the end. The first version might output less than 10 distinct values.